# Is there a way to run code atomically in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, atomic

I'm trying to optimise a piece of code that loads a lot of images from the hard drive and does some computations on it. My first attempt to speed things up was to create an `NSOperationQueue` to load and do the computation in separate `NSOperations` for each image.

Unfortunately that did not really shorten the time taken.

One reason could be the overhead caused by creating the `NSOperations` and adding them to the `queue`. Another possible reason is that the hard drive is not designed to work multithreaded, so instead of reading the files one by one the disk's header needs to jump back and forth between sectors.

So my question would be if there is any way to run **obj-C** or **C** code atomically, so that while one `NSOperation` reads a file it is not disturbed by some operation trying to read another file, but still all `NSOperations` can do their computations on their image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use **GCD** (Grand Central Dispatch) and forget about explicit threading?

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) is a good Apple guide about it

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The chapter that was most useful to me was [Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  It allows you to implement critical sections.